# Invalid field hour for entrytype 'article'

Tags: biblatex, biber

I use `@Article` to cite newspaper articles. Occasionally, the time, not just the date, is a crucial element of the entry. However, when I run `biber -V` I get a warning:

> Invalid field 'hour' for entrytype 'article'

How can I record the time of `@Article` and other entry types? I know I can add `note`, but I'd like to do it 'properly' (*e.g.* have it validly sorted).

---

`.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{DeweyBeatsTruman.bib}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\textcite{Dewey-beats-Truman}
\end{document}
```

`.bib` file:

```
@Article{Dewey-beats-Truman,
  author = {{Chicago Daily Tribune}},
  title  = {Dewey beats Truman},
  date   = {1948-11-02T23:59:00-06:00},
  journal = {Chicago Daily Tribune},
}
```

Biber log file after `biber -V DeweyBeatsTruman`:

```
[0] Config.pm:354> INFO - This is Biber 2.7
[0] Config.pm:357> INFO - Logfile is '.\DeweyBeatsTruman.blg'
[28] biber-MSWIN64:303> INFO - === 
[51] Biber.pm:359> INFO - Reading '.\DeweyBeatsTruman.bcf'
[124] Biber.pm:835> INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
[135] Biber.pm:3670> INFO - Processing section 0
[152] Biber.pm:3840> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'DeweyBeatsTruman.bib' for section 0
[155] bibtex.pm:1435> INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
[158] bibtex.pm:1292> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'DeweyBeatsTruman.bib'
[161] Utils.pm:164> WARN - Datamodel: Entry 'Dewey-beats-Truman' (DeweyBeatsTruman.bib): Invalid field 'hour' for entrytype 'article'
[161] Utils.pm:164> WARN - Datamodel: Entry 'Dewey-beats-Truman' (DeweyBeatsTruman.bib): Invalid field 'minute' for entrytype 'article'
[162] Utils.pm:164> WARN - Datamodel: Entry 'Dewey-beats-Truman' (DeweyBeatsTruman.bib): Invalid field 'second' for entrytype 'article'
[162] Utils.pm:164> WARN - Datamodel: Entry 'Dewey-beats-Truman' (DeweyBeatsTruman.bib): Invalid field 'timezone' for entrytype 'article'
[170] UCollate.pm:68> INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
[170] UCollate.pm:68> INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
[171] Biber.pm:3499> INFO - Sorting list 'nty/global/' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nty' and locale 'en-US'
[171] Biber.pm:3505> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
[173] bbl.pm:608> INFO - Writing '.\DeweyBeatsTruman.bbl' with encoding 'ascii'
[174] bbl.pm:712> INFO - Output to .\DeweyBeatsTruman.bbl
[174] Biber.pm:109> INFO - WARNINGS: 4
```

Output from `\listfiles`:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
biblatex.sty    2016/12/05 v3.7 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
etoolbox.sty    2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 xstring.sty    2013/10/13  v1.7c  String manipulations (C Tellechea)
  blx-dm.def
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def    2016/12/05 v3.7 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.def    2016/12/05 v3.7 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
standard.bbx    2016/12/05 v3.7 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.bbx    2016/12/05 v3.7 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.cbx    2016/12/05 v3.7 biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.cfg    
 english.lbx    2016/12/05 v3.7 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
DeweyBeatsTruman.bbl
```

Comment: What happens if you use `1948-11-02T23:59-06:00Z` (note the `Z` appendage)?

Comment: I don't get a warning of that form (indeed, as there is no `hour` field and as Biber doesn't check for 'extra' fields it would be very odd), though I do get one about the form of the `date` field (once I add the comma missing in your example). Can you expand the code in the question to a full example and include some details about your system, _e.g._ version of Biber (from the `.blg` file), version of `biblatex` (add `\listfiles` to your input and find this in the `.log).

Comment: I've corrected my copy-paste error. Thanks for being patient.

Comment: Save the following line in a new `dbx` file like `test.dbx` and insert the following line `\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[article]{hour,second,minute,timezone}`. In your tex file you can use `\usepackage[datamodel=test]{biblatex}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems as though `blx-dm.cfg` just misses the fields in the datamodel specification. This causes Biber to fail these fields in the datamodel verification. The fields will still work as expected though. I have reported the issue at the `biblatex` bug tracker https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/523.

To fully enjoy the time fields you need to enable them explicitly with `dateusetime=true`, note that with the default `date=comp` times will not be displayed, so I chose `date=short` instead

```
\usepackage[date=short,dateusetime=true]{biblatex}
```

If you want sorting by full date-time, go with

```
\DeclareSortingScheme{ndtt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{month}
    \literal{0}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{day}
    \literal{0}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{hour}
    \literal{0}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{minute}
    \literal{0}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{volume}
    \literal{0}
  }
}
```

This does not take into account times zones and will sort entries with missing month before those that have a month (if you change `\literal{0}` to `\literal{99}`, that is reversed).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[date=short,dateusetime=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Dewey-beats-Truman1,
  author = {{Chicago Daily Tribune}},
  title  = {B},
  date   = {1948-11-02T23:58:00-06:00},
  journal = {Chicago Daily Tribune},
}
@Article{Dewey-beats-Truman2,
  author = {{Chicago Daily Tribune}},
  title  = {A},
  date   = {1948-11-02T23:59:00-06:00},
  journal = {Chicago Daily Tribune},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSortingScheme{ndtt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{month}
    \literal{0}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{day}
    \literal{0}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{hour}
    \literal{0}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{minute}
    \literal{0}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{volume}
    \literal{0}
  }
}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{sorting=ndtt}

\begin{document}
\textcite{Dewey-beats-Truman1,Dewey-beats-Truman2}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This still produces the warning, but it can safely be ignored.

If you want the warnings gone for now, you will need to create a new `.dbx` and load that

Save

```
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{month,day,hour,minute,second,timezone,season,endmonth,endday,endhour,endminute,endsecond,endtimezone,endseason}
```

as `time.dbx` and add `datamodel=time` to the loading time options.